# Как подключить WebCore к своему проекту C++?

Tags: c++, webkit

Хочу подключить WebCore из WebKit'a к своему проекту и на данном этапе встретил несколько проблем.

У WebKita такая структура исходников

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. У WebCore нет API (includes для встраивания). Все заголовки относятся к проекту и некоторые заголовки подключаются из других папок например из WTF или JavaScriptCore
2. При попытке попробовать подключить один заголовочный файл из WebCore , прежде добавив в VS17 дополнительные директории для инклудов

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <WebCore/html/HTMLDocument.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

Вылетают ошибки из WebCore/html/HTMLDocument.h о том, что не найдены подключаемые заголовочные файлы. Потому что пути указаны относительно проекта WebKit

**Собственно вопросы:**

1. Как правильно подключать такие проекты ?
2. Необходимо править исходный код WebCore (правит пути подключаемых *.h файлов)?
3. Как правильно подключать заголовочные файлы , когда не предоставляют API ?
4. Или прежде WebCore должен собраться с помощью CMake? Только потом уже использоваться в моем проекте ?
5. Почему например: В WebCore используются заголовочные файлы и подключаются они как `<JavaScriptCore/header1.h>` Когда header1.h находится в `JavaScriptCore/dir1/header1.h` ?

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: У WebCore есть собственный CMakeLists.txt и make. Стоит попробовать использовать CMake или make для включения этого модуля в ваш проект. Вполне возможно, что WebCore принципиально не может быть отдельно использован. В этом случае только собирать свою версию по крупицам.

Comment: считаю что подключать сторонние библиотеки через vs совсем не благородно. Если вам нужно могу написать cmake для подключения этой либы

Comment: @jNX Было бы здорово , дайте ваши контакты

Comment: напишите лучше вы свою почту что бы мне не стали ломиться куча людей)

Comment: пришло ?  я написал